# Should I use "as" or "since" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I resolved to reveal my plan, **as/since** my hopes of hiring Tom returned
>   after he’d shared his story with me.

Is **as** or **since** the correct choice here? And why?

Comment: I notice that more and more young people say "as" here, but "since" has long been the stylistically natural choice. It's certainly my choice. Also, you may freely ignore any pedants who rule out one or both in favour of "because".

Answer (score 1):

Either sounds fine to me. I think that "since" tends to be used in speech more than "as." I think that in writing they're used equally often. When I use "since," I usually don't include a comma before because it introduces a subordinate clause (in the same way that I wouldn't put a comma before "because"). When I use "as," I do include the comma for some reason that I can't entirely describe. (It's almost like it's more of a modifying phrase and less of a subordinate clause to me.)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use either "as" or "since." I'd use "because."